# Display json data from jQuery.ajax in HTML using loop

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

Hello suppose I have the following ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://myurl.com",
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

That results in the following json data (in my console)

```
{
  "meta": {
    "last_updated": "2017-07-06"
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "term": "DRUG INEFFECTIVE",
      "count": 1569
    },
    {
      "term": "NAUSEA",
      "count": 1374
    },
    {
      "term": "FATIGUE",
      "count": 1371
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I populate a `div` in my HTML page with this data in a format something like:

```
term: x
count: xx

term: x
count: xx

term: x
count: xx
```

I am not interested in the "meta" stuff only the "results"

Anyone know how to use a simple loop to display this data?

Thanks!

Comment: within `success: function(data) { ... }` "for loop" through `data.results` and then use jQuery to populate the targeted div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through your `data.results` within your "success function", like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://myurl.com",
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);

        jQuery.each(data.results, function(i, val) {
            // here you can do your magic
            $("#yourdivid").append(document.createTextNode(val.term));
            $("#yourdivid").append(document.createTextNode(val.count));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you chris, can you help me out with what to put in the createTextNode?

Comment: awesome thank you very much this is exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You want the success data which you receive in json format and for that, you first need to convert it in array to get the data

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

this will help you to receive the data in an array format and then you will do whatever you want to do with the data.

For more info look at these answers [How to display JSON data with jQuery Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419183/how-to-display-json-data-with-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score -1):

```
StudentViewModel EmpInfo = new StudentViewModel();

        HttpClient client1 = new HttpClient();
        client1.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2585/");

        client1.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var responsecountry = client1.GetAsync("api/Country/").Result;
        List<SelectListItem> country = new List<SelectListItem>();


        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2585/");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = client.GetAsync("api/StudentApi/" + id).Result;


        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StudentViewModel>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            if (responsecountry.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                country = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SelectListItem>>(responsecountry.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                EmpInfo.Country = country;
            }
            return PartialView(EmpInfo);
        }
```

Comment: this might be a valid answer, but clearly not for that question (which happens to already have an accepted answer)